# How to retrieve array from void function and pass to other functions in Main?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

**I am a beginner in C**

I have a problem in which I am passing an array of grades to main and will need to convert those grades to `int`s and find the min max and avg of them.

The specifications are

- `void getGrade(int argc, char *argv[])`
- `int findMaximum(grade[])`
- `int findMinimum(grade[])`
- `float calculateAverage(grade[])`
- `printResults(max, min, avg)`

and these must all be called in order in the main function.

**I am trying to figure out how to access the array "grade" manipulated in getGrade, to be able to pass it to the other functions in main.**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    getGrade(argc, argv)
    int max = findMaximum(grade);
    int min = findMinimum(grade);
    float avg = calculateAverage(grade);
    print results(max, min, avg);
    return 0;
}

void getGrade(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    int grade[argc - 1];
    for(i=0, i<argc -1; i++){
        grade[i] = atoi(*(argv + i + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: If `getGrade()` doesn't take `grade` as an argument or return it as a value, that must mean that it's a global variable.

Comment: `grade` cannot be accessed outside of that function because it exists at local scope.  You will either need to allocate it on the heap with a `malloc` family call, declare it in main and pass a reference to it into your `getGrade` function, or declare it global (not recommended)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons He seems to have been given the signature of `getGrade()` as a requirement, so it doesn't look like he can pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: @Barmar yuck, then I guess the global scope is the only option.  Don't like using global scope when it can be avoided.

Comment: There are only two ways to get something "out" of a function: by return value, or by pointer argument (well, OK, there's globals, but don't do that).

Comment: for a global variable, it can be declared outside of main as "int grade[]" and when it is manipulated in getGrade, the new "grade[]" will then be passed onto the functions?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I have been told it can be done with multiple pointers, but the specifications dont allow me to add arguments

Comment: If you can't add a return value, and you can't add a pointer argument, then you can't get any data out of it and its very existence as a function is pointless. Given these constraints, using a global is the only options, so the "correct" thing to do is just modify the global and not use the function at all. Oh, and tell your teacher he's a moron.

Comment: If you cannot modify the function prototype because of the insane specification, you could call `getGrade` in `main` and call all other function inside `getGrade`. I don't like the solution of having to use a global variable, that's insane, that's what the function arguments are for.

Comment: The only reasonable interpretation for a beginner project in C is that `grade` is declared as a global array holding some `MAX` fixed number of integers. (e.g. `#define MAX 50 ... int grade[MAX];`) You will read the grades as text from `argv` in `getgrade` (C style doesn't use `camelCase` function names) and convert them to integer values, keeping a count of the number converted to insure you attempt to store no more than `MAX` values in the array. Passing `grade` to the other functions makes little sense if `grade` is global. (time for a new prof.)

Answer (score 0):

The array `grade` can't be accessed outside of that function because it is local variable inside `getGrade` function.

You'll have to first fill the `grade` array and then pass it to other functions.
<sub>I don't recommend make it global variable.</sub>

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // Allocate memory for grade.

    int* grade = malloc( (argc -1 )* sizeof(int) );

    // Pass additional parameter, for number of items in grade array.

    getGrade(grade , argc -1, argv );
    int max = findMaximum(grade, argc -1 );
    int min = findMinimum(grade, argc -1 );
    float avg = calculateAverage(grade, argc -1 );
    /*print*/ results(max, min, avg);

    free(grade); // Release the memory

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are using `malloc`, please check that it doesn't return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The `grade` array is a local variable in `getGrade`, so when the function exits,
the variable and their contents are lost.

You have to create the array prior of the calls of this functions and pass the
array and its length to the function. You will need to modify the functions to
accept the length as well:

```
void getGrade(grade, size_t len, char **argv);
int findMaximum(int *grade, size_t len);
int findMinimum(int *grade, size_t len);
float calculateAverage(int *grade, size_t len);
printResults(max, min, avg);


void getGrade(grade, size_t len, char **argv)
{
    for(size_t i = 0, i < len; i++)
        grade[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int grades[argc - 1];
    size_t len = argc - 1;

    getGrade(grades, len, argv);

    int max = findMaximum(grades, len);
    int min = findMinimum(grades, len);
    float avg = calculateAverage(grades, len);
    print results(max, min, avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several alternatives:

- Make the array `static`.  The array `grade` has been declared automatic variable (that only exists during its scope delimiters, which are the function body.  But if you make it `static` it extends its life to all the program life (its a global variable, despite the fact that its name can be used only inside the function body).  Then `return` a pointer to it.

  ```
  int *getGrade(int argc, char *argv[]){
      int i;
      static int grade[argc - 1];
      for(i=0; i<argc -1; i++){
          grade[i] = atoi(*(argv + i + 1));
      }
      return grade;
  }
  ```

  This has the inconvenient of not *being reentrant*, so you cannot have several threads making use of the function at the same time, as it has global data.  Also, you cannot call the function until you have completely used the value from the last call, as there is only one array `grade`.
- Allocate an array with `malloc(3)` and return it's pointer.  Later, when you don't need the pointer anymore, you can `free(3)` it, so its memory is returned to the system.

  ```
  int *getGrade(int argc, char *argv[]){
      int i;
      int *grade = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof *grade);
      for(i=0; i<argc -1; i++){
          grade[i] = atoi(*(argv + i + 1));
      }
      return grade;
  }
  ```

  The inconvenient is that you don't know (a priory) the number of allocated elements, so you have to provide it somehow.  (In this case, you allocate `argc - 1` elements, so you know the array size.  **Reentrancy**:  The reentrancy of this function depends on the reentrancy of the `malloc(3)` function.   Nowadays, almost all implementations of `malloc(3)` can be used in different threads.
- Pass it from the calling routine.  This way you can decide, at each function call, the actual array, array size, and other aspects.

  ```
  int *getGrade(int argc, char *argv[], int *passed_grade, int size)
  {
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<argc - 1; i++){
          passed_grade[i] = atoi(*(argv + i + 1)); /* <== I don't understand why you don't write argv[i + 1] instead of this unreadable thing (APART THAT IT'S INCORRECT) */
      }
      return passed_grade;  /* returning it makes it possible to use this function in an expression. */
  }

  ...

  /* then, in main() */
  #define N (argc - 1)

  int grade[N];
  int min = findMinimum(getGrade(argc, argv, grade, N), N);
  int max = findMaximum(grade, N); /* grade has already been initialized in last line */
  ```

  The inconvenient in this approach is to carry two more parameters than previously, but it allows to use different array sizes and. **Reentrancy**: This function reentrancy depends on the passed array not being global.

In my humble opinion, the third approach is the best, as it doesn't depend normally on the possible blocking of the `malloc(3)` routine  (malloc can be blocked if used by several threads in some implementations), and doesn't depend on a `static` global data (making it not reentrant).

## NOTES

- your posted code has several compilation errors (mainly syntax: a semicolon is missing between the two first expresions in the `for` loop; and a problem with the index used to access the `argv` array)
- The last point, makes it impossible to compile and test your sample code without first converting it to a compilable example.   DON'T DO THAT!!!  Post a complete, testable and verifiable example, as we cannot guess what are simple typos or what is a concept error in your side.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info.